# Obtener valores de una tabla - jquery - ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

¿Como puedo recorrer las filas de una tabla HTML y obtener los valores de una celda con un botón?
Estoy realizando una aplicacion en php y necesito enviar unos datos obtenidos de una tabla mediante ajax a otro archivo de php. Ya obtuve el valor de una celda especifica, el problema es que al hacer el envio no me esta recibiendo uno de los datos especificamente:

`idcita = $(this).html() + "\n";`


Este es el error que me muestra:

> Notice: Undefined index: idcita in C:\xampp\htdocs\uci_citas\modelo_tabla.php on line 3

Esto son los archivos que estoy manejando:

## Script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.enviar').on('click', function() {
            /*var tags_td = new Array();
            var tags_td=document.getElementsByName('n');
            var att = document.getElementsByName('atendido');
            var celda = 0;*/
            var idcita = "";
            var atendido = $("#atendido").val();

            // Obtenemos todos los valores contenidos en los <td> de la fila
            // seleccionada
            $(this).parents("tr").find(".n").each(function() {
              idcita = $(this).html() + "\n";
            });

            console.log(idcita);

            $.ajax({
                    data:  {idcita:idcita, atendido:atendido}, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
                    url:   'modelo_tabla.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
                    type:  'POST', //método de envio
                    success:  function (response) {
                        location.href='citas.php';
                    }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

## funciones.php:

```
<?php
    function tabla(){
        try {
            include_once("conexion.php");
            $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
            $stmt = $con_bd->prepare('SET max_join_size=18446744073709551615');
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt = $con_bd->prepare('SELECT * FROM solicitar_cita WHERE dia = :dia ORDER BY hora ASC');
            $stmt->bindParam(':dia', $fecha);
            $stmt->execute();
            $rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $i = -1;

            if (!empty($rs)) {
                $tabla = "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive' id='tabla_datos'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr class='bg-primary'>
                                    <th scope='col'>ID</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Nombre</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Apellido</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Identificacion</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Celular</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Direccion</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Correo</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Hora</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Atendido</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Boton</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>";
                            "<tbody>";
                foreach ($rs as $resultado) {
                    $i = $i+1;
                    $val = ($resultado['atendido'] == 1) ? 1 : 1;
                    $tabla .= "<tr>
                                    <td class='n'>".$resultado['idsolicitar_cita']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['nombre']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['apellido']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['identificacion']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['celular']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['direccion']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['correo']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['hora']."</td>
                                    <td>".$retVal = ($resultado['atendido'] == 1) ? 'Si' : 'No'."</td>
                                    <input type='hidden' id='atendido' name='atendido' value=".$val.">
                                    <input type='hidden' id='idu' name='idu' value=".$resultado['idsolicitar_cita'].">
                                    <td><button id='enviar' name='enviar' class='enviar'><img src='img/checkmark.png' width='15px' height='15px' ".$Val = ($resultado['atendido'] == 1) ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'."></button></td>
                                </tr>";
                }
                $tabla .= "</tbody>
                        </table>";
            }
            echo $tabla;    
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(). '<br/>';
        }
    }
?>
```

## modelo_tabla.php

```
<?php
    $atendido = $_POST['atendido'];
    $idu = $_POST['idcita'];
    try {
        include_once("conexion.php");
        $stmt = $con_bd->prepare('UPDATE solicitar_cita SET atendido = :atendido WHERE idsolicitar_cita = :idu');
        $stmt->bindParam(':atendido', $atendido);
        $stmt->bindParam(':idu', $idu);
        $rows = $stmt->execute();
        $com = '';
        if ($rows) {
            $com = 'completado';
            echo $com;
        }       
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agradezco a @JavierGarcía por ofrecer su ayuda, Finalmente, pude encontrar el problema, lo que sucedia era que la accion por defecto del evento afectaba el envio de los datos, solo necesitaba implementar la linea:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Con eso funciono perfectamente, dejo el codigo de los tres archivos como estan funcionando, para quien llegue a tener el mismo problema:

### **script:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabla_datos').on('click', '.enviar', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // cancela el evento por defecto ***MUY IMPORTANTE PARA EL FUNCIONAMIENTO**

        var filaactual = $(this).closest("tr"); // obtiene la fila actual

        var cita = filaactual.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // obtiene el valor del primer TD de la fila actual

        var atendido = $("#atendido").val();


        var parametros = {
            cita: cita,
            atendido: atendido
        };

        $.ajax({
            type:  'POST', //método de envio
            data:  parametros, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
            url:   'modelo_tabla.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            success:  function (response) {
                        location.href='citas.php';
                      }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

### **funciones.php**

```
<?php
    function tabla(){
        try {
            include_once("conexion.php");
            $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
            $stmt = $con_bd->prepare('SET max_join_size=18446744073709551615');
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt = $con_bd->prepare('SELECT * FROM solicitar_cita WHERE dia = :dia ORDER BY hora ASC');
            $stmt->bindParam(':dia', $fecha);
            $stmt->execute();
            $rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $i = 0;

            if (!empty($rs)) {
                $tabla = "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive' id='tabla_datos'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr class='bg-primary'>
                                    <th scope='col'>ID</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Nombre</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Apellido</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Identificacion</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Celular</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Direccion</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Correo</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Hora</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Atendido</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Boton</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>";
                            "<tbody>";
                foreach ($rs as $resultado) {
                    $i = $i+1;
                    $val = ($resultado['atendido'] == 1) ? 1 : 1;
                    $tabla .= "<tr>
                                    <td class='n'>".$resultado['idsolicitar_cita']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['nombre']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['apellido']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['identificacion']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['celular']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['direccion']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['correo']."</td>
                                    <td>".$resultado['hora']."</td>
                                    <td>".$retVal = ($resultado['atendido'] == 1) ? 'Si' : 'No'."</td>
                                    <input type='hidden' id='atendido' name='atendido' value=".$val.">
                                    <td><button id='enviar' name='enviar' class='enviar'><img src='img/checkmark.png' width='15px' height='15px' ".$Val = ($resultado['atendido'] == 1) ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'."></button></td>
                                </tr>";
                }
                $tabla .= "</tbody>
                        </table>";
            }
            echo $tabla;    
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(). '<br/>';
        }
    }
?>
```

### **modelo_tabla.php**

```
<?php
    $atendido = $_POST['atendido'];
    $idcita = $_POST['cita'];
    try {
        include_once("conexion.php");
        $stmt = $con_bd->prepare('UPDATE solicitar_cita SET atendido = :atendido WHERE idsolicitar_cita = :idcita');
        $stmt->bindParam(':atendido', $atendido);
        $stmt->bindParam(':idcita', $idcita);
        $rows = $stmt->execute();
        $com = '';
        if ($rows) {
            $com = 'completado';
            echo $com;
        }       
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Dejo link de dos paginas que fueron de mucha ayuda para solucionar este inconveniente:

[jQuery How to Get Table Cell Value TD Value [4 ways]](https://codepedia.info/jquery-get-table-cell-td-value-div/)

[Receiving Multiple Parameters into PHP from jQuery Ajax Call](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/receiving-multiple-parameters-into-php-from-jquery-ajax-call/27761)

Answer (score 0):

Tu variable idcita almacenará solo el último valor de los elementos con clase .n, si requieres un unico valor accede: `$(this).parents("tr").find("#idelemento")` de lo contrario si vas a recorrer asegurate de concatenar `idcita += $(this).text()`

Veo el ajax correcto, revisa la pestaña network de tu navegador y observa si en la solicitud el valor idcita está presente.

Intenta recuperando en tu modelo con `$_REQUEST['idcita']`

Comment: Hola y gracias por responder @JavierGarcia, acabo de intentar lo que me comentaste y aun no funciona, no utilizo el id del elemento por que estoy obteniendo la informacion de un td, aunque el valor si lo estoy obteniendo ya, el problema esta en el envio de los datos, como lo comente arriba la variable idcita me aparece indefinida a pesar de que si tiene el valor guardado pues en consola lo muestra, lo que he notado es que el problema esta en la forma en que esta tomando el valor esa variable, me refiero a `idcita = $(this).html() + "\n";`